# How to disable all tabs except selected tab in angular4 material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm very new to angular and material and having a hard problem of disabling the non-selected tabs in angular 4 material and I have only this code below.

```
    <md-tab-group class="flex-stretch tab-button-arrows">

      <md-tab *ngFor="let subject of subjects" label="subject.name" ></md-tab>

    </md-tab-group>
```

*Note:* The **subjects**  is a dynamic array.

Comment: This is old material (new material uses `<mat-...>` instead of `<md-...>`), why not update your material to a newer version?

Comment: @Guntram ohhh, thank you for reminding me about the newer version :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All you need to do is use default property of `mat-tab` `isActive` : [**ReadMore**](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api)

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab #tab [disabled]='!tab.isActive' *ngFor="let subject of subjects" [label]="subject.name">
    {{ subject.name }}
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disabl-not-active-tab)**

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [disabled] tag to your mat-tab, with a function linked to it. And have a index for each tab.
Something like this:

```
<md-tab-group class="flex-stretch tab-button-arrows" [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">

      <md-tab [disabled]="isSelected(i)" *ngFor="let subject of subjects; let i = index" label="subject.name" ></md-tab>

    </md-tab-group>
```

Then you declare the function on your component to disable if true:

```
isSelected(index: number) {
        if (this.selectedIndex == index) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Terrible idea to assign functions to attribute bindings. That function is going to be called tons of times. The best way to avoid that is to write the expression directly in the template like selectedIndex !== i

Answer (score 1):

By Default Selected Tab Will Display You Can........

```html
 <button mat-raised-button (click)="demo1BtnClick()">Tab Demo 1!</button>
<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="demo1TabIndex">
   <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
   <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
   <mat-tab label="Tab 3">Conte`enter code here`nt 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: But that is not the question

Comment: This helped me realize that `[(selectedIndex)]` emits the selected index which fixed an issue I had when using `[selectedIndex]`.